# Making fluid 3x3 grid display of 9 divs

Tags: jquery, html, css

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/metacode/LEVtv/)  |  [**FullScreen**](http://jsfiddle.net/metacode/LEVtv/show/)

### EDIT : [Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/metacode/6erX8/)  |  [FullScreen](http://jsfiddle.net/metacode/6erX8/show)

In the code above, i successfully managed to make a `3x3` grid of 9 `div`s (8 cloned via `jQuery`). The grid is centered horizontally but not vertically. Is there any not too complex way to center is vertically (CSS solution preferred).

Also, I have to use `!important` in CSS to give `div#game1` `min-height` and `min-width` which I am not happy about. Is there any other way to do this?

---

### EDIT: Updated Code

**jQuery**

```
(function($) {
    var $game1 = $('div#game1');
    var $game2 = $('div#game2');

    for (var i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        $game1.append($('div.frame').eq(0).clone());
    }

    var $frame = $game1.find('div.frame');

    $(window).on('resize', function() {
        var windowW = window.innerWidth, windowH = window.innerHeight;
        var gameLen = windowW < windowH ? windowW : windowH;
        $game1.css({
            'width':  gameLen + 'px',
            'height': gameLen + 'px'
        });
    });
    $(window).trigger('resize');

})(jQuery);
```

**HTML**

```
    <div id="game1">
    <!-- this is one frame. Its cloned and repeated 8 more times -->
    <div data-win="-" class="frame">
        <div data-sign="-" class="signbox"></div>
        <div data-sign="-" class="signbox"></div>
        <div data-sign="-" class="signbox"></div>
        <div data-sign="-" class="signbox"></div>
        <div data-sign="-" class="signbox"></div>
        <div data-sign="-" class="signbox"></div>
        <div data-sign="-" class="signbox"></div>
        <div data-sign="-" class="signbox"></div>
        <div data-sign="-" class="signbox"></div>
        <div class="winsign"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
html, body {
    width: 100%; height: 100%;
    min-width: 500px;
    min-height: 500px;
    margin: 0;
    font-family: 'Open sans', sans-serif;
}

body {
    background-image: -webkit-radial-gradient(circle farthest-side, #F8F8F8 0%, #EDEDED 100%);
    background-image:    -moz-radial-gradient(circle farthest-side, #F8F8F8 0%, #EDEDED 100%);
    background-image:     -ms-radial-gradient(circle farthest-side, #F8F8F8 0%, #EDEDED 100%);
    background-image:      -o-radial-gradient(circle farthest-side, #F8F8F8 0%, #EDEDED 100%);
    background-image:         radial-gradient(circle farthest-side, #F8F8F8 0%, #EDEDED 100%);
}

div {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

#game1, #game2 {
    min-width: 500px;
    min-height: 500px;
    margin: auto;
}

.frame {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    width: 32%; height: 32%;
    margin: 0.66%;
}

.frame > .winsign {
    width: 100%; height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; left: 0;
}

.frame .signbox {
    float:  left;
    width: 33.33%; height:  33.33%;
    border: 0px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
    overflow: hidden;
}

.frame:nth-child(1) { background: rgba(255, 0, 0, .3);   }
.frame:nth-child(2) { background: rgba(0, 255, 0, .3);   }
.frame:nth-child(3) { background: rgba(0, 0, 255, .3);   }
.frame:nth-child(4) { background: rgba(111, 111, 0, .3); }
.frame:nth-child(5) { background: rgba(0, 111, 255, .3); }
.frame:nth-child(6) { background: rgba(255, 0, 121, .3); }
.frame:nth-child(7) { background: rgba(77, 25, 255, .3); }
.frame:nth-child(8) { background: rgba(12, 12, 123, .3); }
.frame:nth-child(9) { background: rgba(255, 255, 5, .3); }
```

Comment: Why exactly did you have to use !important?

Comment: The min, max width was not working unless I use `!important` because maybe the inline styles from jQuery were overriding it

Comment: Aha, yes if there are inline styles, `!important` is the only thing that will override it.

Comment: Silly me! I don't really need `!important` because jQuery adds `width` inline not `min-width`. So it works the same even without `!important`.

Answer (score 0):

There is a BUG with display:inline-block in class frame, you can replace with float: left.

Comment: I changed the display to floats. But `inline-block` don't have bug. [**Read This.**)(http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/). But that's doesn't solve vertical centering problem.

Comment: Haha,Thanks! But sometime google translate will make some mistakes.

Comment: No. I decided to ignore the vertical centering problem and work on rest of the code. Its a game actually, [**Ultimate Tic-Tac-Toe**](http://mathwithbaddrawings.com/2013/06/16/ultimate-tic-tac-toe/)